# Testing space-time warp on a smaller scale, "Breaking the Warp Barrier: Hyper-Fast Solitons in Einstein-Maxwell-Plasma Theory"

Tags: general-relativity, faster-than-light, solitons, warp-drives

So according to this paper it creates a warp drive without the need of negative energy to operate which many think does not exist in reality.

So my question is what would you do to experimentally verify the theory of this paper, for instance could you create an Electro Magnetic soliton around a single particle then check if the distance is contracting between one particle in front of it and expanding from behind another particle without actually moving the particle in the soliton? test the theory on a smaller scale because of energy requirements?

https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.07125

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/632346/2451