# Warp drive small scale experiments "proof of concept"

Tags: general-relativity, faster-than-light, solitons, warp-drives

Possible small scale warp drive experiments, or small scale experiments with quantum mechanics to model space-time warping? Why is it so difficult to engineer a small scale warp drive even though negative energy is not required to build a warp drive? According to this paper negative energy is not needed https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.07125

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/632346/2451

Comment: Its not a duplicate I am asking for opinion's on experimental evidence of warp drives I am just stating that the mathematical model of a warp drive in that paper does not need negative energy

Comment: even if the results are correct, the energy required is unrealistically large according to him -- something around tenth of a solar mass if you want velocities around the speed of light.

Comment: If you could create a warp bubble a few sizes larger than an atom and accelerate it across the universe would it still require the same amount of energy?

Comment: Even a working warp drive proof of concept would be great, any ideas?